# Backbone events not being bound

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, jplayer, backbone-events

Can anyone tell me why the "click" events in the PlayerView code below are not being correctly bound/fired?  I feel like I'm missing something very obvious, but after hours of trying many different solutions, I am at a loss.

This is how it's being instantiated in the router:

```
App.playerView = new App.Views.PlayerView
  el: $("#player")
  collection: App.tracks
```

and here is the actual view code (in Coffeescript with jPlayer plugin code in case it's related):

```
App.Views.PlayerView = Backbone.View.extend
  events:
    "click .jp-next": "next"
    "click .jp-back": "back"

  initialize: ->
    _.bindAll @, 'render'
    @template = _.template $('#player-template').html()
    @collection.bind 'reset', @render
    @render()

  play: (track) ->
    ...

  next: ->
    ...

  back: ->
    ...

  render: ->
    $(@el).html @template {}
    @player = $("#jplayer").jPlayer
      "swfPath": "/"
      ready: =>
        @next()
      ended: =>
        @next()
    @
```

Comment: #player is in the DOM, and I have looked at the template (can post that if it helps) for problems but found nothing.  I also though that perhaps jPlayer was creating the trouble, but could find no proof of that either in the source code.  However, since it does seem to work in Backbone, jPlayer is the likely culprit.

Answer (score 1):

Try @delegateEvents() in render

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out, and it was jPlayer related.  jPlayer was somehow overriding the events after the fact, so I just removed that functionality in their script to get it to work.  What a pain, but thanks for all who helped!